# How to insert into associative table in many to many relationship by Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, associations

I have two tables Student and Course with many to many relationship.

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="students")
    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();

    ...
    // getters and setters
}


@Entity
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    ...
    // getters and setters
}
```

I am using Hibernate and Persistence API to do the mapping
Let's say I have 5 courses in the Course table:

```
Id  Name
1  Course1
2  Course2
3  Course3
4  Course4
5  Course5
```

The Student table starts with zero records. Once a student is inserted into the Student table, i.e.

```
Id  Name
1  Student1
```

I also need to insert at least one record into the CourseStudent table. Let's say Stduent1 takes three course Course1, Course2 and Course3, then I need to insert:

```
StudentId CourseID
1         1
1         2
1         3
```

The difficulty I am having now is that, in my data model, I don't have the CourseStudent class, but only Student and Course and their mapping @many_to_many. This table CourseStudent is created and managed by Hibernate, and its mapping class CourseStudent seems unnecessary.

In this situation, how can I insert records into an associative table which doesn't have an object mapping in the model? Do I have to explicitly create a class CourseStudent to achieve this, so that I can persist data into the associative table?

Comment: Specify cascade on the mapping: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html#cascade()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't have to. It should be as simple as adding the courses to the list of courses of the student and update (save)  the student.

But keep in mind: As of my knowledge hibernate is not able to keep bi-directional relations updated on its own. That means you would have to add the student on each course to the students list and save the course as well.

Hope this helps

Comment: I did this, " as simple as adding the courses to the list of courses of the student and update (save) the student.", and then checked the CourseStudent table, it doesn't change at all. Do I have to complete the second part too "you would have to add the student on each course to the students list and save the course as well."?

Comment: I mean once I added the courses to the list of courses of the student and update (save) the student, I should see the CourseStudent table change. Right?

Comment: Depending on your transaction handling you may have to commit the session to see the changes in the database.

Comment: Has anyone found an answer to this issue? I am facing the same issue, but I am loading the @ManyToMany relation Lazily.

At first, I updated the object from the controller, but it overwrote the entry in the DB, which is NOT what I wanted. Then, I tried saving it, but got NullPointerException errors.

Thanks!